# SNMPv3 traps on Catalyst 9500

Tags: cisco-catalyst, snmp, ios-xe

with our new Catalyst 9500 switches we want to use snmpv3 to send traps.

Thats what I configured:

```
snmp-server engineID local 1234567890ABCEDF
snmp-server group SG_SERVERFARM v3 priv
snmp-server trap-source Vlan%NUMBER%
snmp-server enable traps
snmp-server user SNMP_USER SG_SERVERFARM v3 auth md5 %PASSWORD1% priv aes 256 %PASSWORD2%
snmp-server host %IP-TRAP RECEIVER% vrf %VRF-NAME% version 3 priv SNMP_USER
```

To check if the problem is on the switch I debug ip packets with the following access-list

```
access-list 2000 permit ip host %IP-TRAP RECEIVER% any
access-list 2000 permit ip any host %IP-TRAP RECEIVER%
debug ip packet 2000
```

I see no packet if I trigger an event that should send a trap like create a vlan and delete a vlan.
both trap configurations I can see in the running config

```
snmp-server enable traps vlancreate
snmp-server enable traps vlandelete
```

The access from the NMS systems to the switch via SNMPv3 is working.

Any idea what is missing or what I did wrong?

Kind regards

Christoph

Comment: What, specifically, are you doing to create or delete a VLAN to try to generate a trap?

Comment: vlan %xyz% name %abcd% and no vlan %xyz%